# How to add Attribute to XMLLIST without looping in E4X

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4, xmllist

I have the following xml

```
var xml:XML = <test>
    <node id='1'/>
    <node id='2'/>
    <node id='3'/>
    <node id='4'/>
    <node id='5'/>
</test>;

var xmlist:XMLList = xml.children();

for each (var node:XML in xmlist) 
{
    node.@newAttribute = "1";
}
```

I'm looping through each node and adding an attribute. How can I do this without looping? I've tried this

```
xmlist.attributes().@newAttrib = "1";
```

but I'm getting the error  "**TypeError: Error #1089: Assignment to lists with more than one item is not supported**."

Comment: What is the issue you want to overcome? is it speed or tersness of exression?

Comment: I'm looking for terseness and also speed, why i need to loop over all the nodes to add an attribute ? it will be more convenient if i can achieve the same in a single line of code.

Comment: if you want to do it in 1 LOC, why dont you wrap it in an function call?

Comment: yeah i can do like that, but my requirement is i have do to it without using any looping statements, i need any predefined syntax in e4x to add an attribute for all xml items in xmllist from [0]..[n] .

Comment: Actually the only way in a pure XML environment would be via XSLT ;-) I guess you will prefer the way you are doing just right now

Answer (score 1):

it's been 2 weeks since this question is asked but there will always be more people in need of help.

TypeError: Error #1089 is caused by result of more than one objects in xml.

Normally I took this error by something like this operation= xml.classes.(@id==1).students.(@no==2).@Grade="A";
The error caused because there were more than one students in the xml.classes, so it tried to return all of them. As the error says : "Assignment to lists with more than one item is not supported." You cannot assign a value to more than one object at the same time.

And since you add all the  s into the XMLList, I'm not sure of the reason since I don't use XMLList. it's a useless as I think. So if you change your code as

```
var xml:XML = <test>
    <node id='1'/>
    <node id='2'/>
    <node id='3'/>
    <node id='4'/>
    <node id='5'/>
</test>;


for each (var n:XML in xml) 
{
    n.@newAttribute = "1";
}
```

The problem should be solved.
But I would suggest you to use "id" as a unique key. Then you can use that unique key to reach specific items in the XML, like

```
xml.node.(@id=="1").@newAttribute="1";
```

I hope this helps you. Take care

-Ozan

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, it's not supported. Since you cannot do this assignment to multiple elements, I don't see a way to do this without iterating over the xml.

For fun, I tried this and got the same error: `xml.node.@newAttribute=1`

It's just a slightly more terse version of:

```
var xmlist:XMLList = xml.children();
xmlist.attributes().@newAttrib = "1";
```

Comment: hi sunil i too tried the same but no use, thanks for trying....can we achieve that by any other means in e4x?